# Remove repeated word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to develop a program in which it takes in a user inputted string, e.g:

```
'to be or not to be'.
```

Then separate the string into its separate words:

```
'to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be'
```

The words are then put into a list:

```
['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
```

However, if a word is repeated, only the first use of the word is counted and replaced with its position number. So, for example, both `to` in `to be or not to be` will be counted as 1. This is because the word `to` is repeated and so the first appearance of `to` accounts for both of the words. After the words are replaced with their position number, the sentence should be recreated with these numbers. So `to be or not to be` should become:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2
```

The list of both words and numbers should be saved as either separate files or one single file. 
This is all i have so far:

```
UserSentence = input('Enter your chosen sentence: ') #this is where the user inputs their sentence
UserSentence = UserSentence.split()#.split()takes the inputted string and breaks it down into individual words...
                               #... and turns it into a list
List1 = UserSentence
List2 = UserSentence
```

Comment: That's hardly enough to justify asking on SO, in my opinion.

Comment: I've figured out how to remove repeated words from the list

Comment: You need to show that you made an effort to solve this...

Comment: I've been doing this for days fam

Comment: What about reading the doc to start with ? Like, what methods are availables on a `list` ?

Comment: why isn't anyone changing the topic of the question its hardly relevent

Comment: @K.Ruddick - Was my answer helpful? You have not selected an answer as correct yet. Was wondering if you needed more help.

Comment: @deltashade yea it worked great, apart from saving to a single/separate file, apart from that it is great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you would go about this is first you would get the input, like you have done. Afterwards you would split like you were doing. Then you would want to go through each word, and in an another list append the position by using the index method of list. That will give you first appearance of each of the word, and you want to add 1 so you get position of word the way you want. Here is a sample code. Please understand and ask any questions you have on this.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()

position = []
for word in words:
    position.append(words.index(word) + 1)

print(position)
```

here is sample output:

```
>>> Enter a sentence: to be or not to be
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to understand same thing. I guess because the person who asked did not provide any of his code? I mean he did provide the first few steps. He just didnt understand how to use some basic built in functions. This is what the website is for.

Comment: I downvoted - I don't appreciate encouraging question-askers that split a string and then turn to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possibly because of the redundant `index()` calls and the off-by-one error in the result. And now possibly because of the unnecessary image that could've been text.

Comment: @DonkeyKong. Brutal.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 2.7
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ") will error out.
Just replace input with raw_input

Above code is solid example of concise coding.

Hi Riddick,
Just FYI,
Below code will retain the order & delete the duplicates from the words list. In case, you want to modify user's input & then do your index activity,

unique_1 = []
[unique_1.append(item) for item in words if item not in unique_1]

Hope it helps,